# How to calculate tiered pricing using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I'm trying to calculate tiered rates for a stay at some lodging. Lets say we have a weekly, half week, and daily rate for a property.

```
period_name | nights | rate
-------------------------------------
WEEK        | 7      | 100
HALFWEEK    | 3      | 50
DAY         | 1      | 25
```

How would I query this with a total number of nights and get a break down of what periods qualify, going from longest to shortest? Some examples results

**10 nights**

We break 10 into (7 days) + (3 days). The 7 days will be at the WEEK rate (100). The 3 days will be at the HALFWEEK rate (50). Here it qualifies for (1 WEEK @ 100) + (1 HALFWEEK @ 50)

```
period_name | nights | rate | num | subtotal
----------------------------------------------
WEEK        | 7      | 100  | 1   | 100
HALFWEEK    | 3      | 50   | 1   | 50
```

**4 nights**

We break 4 into (3 days) + (1 day). The 3 days will be at the HALFWEEK rate (50). The 1 day will be at the DAY rate (25). Here it qualifies for (1 HALFWEEK @ 50) + (1 DAY @ 25)

```
period_name | nights | rate | num | subtotal
----------------------------------------------
HALFWEEK    | 3      | 50   | 1   | 50
DAY         | 1      | 25   | 1   | 25
```

**16 nights**

We break 16 into (14 days) + (2 days). The 14 days will be at the WEEK rate (multiplied by 2), (100 * 2). The 2 days will be at the DAY rate (2 x 25). Here it qualifies for (2 WEEK @ 100) + (2 DAY @ 25)

```
period_name | nights | rate | num | subtotal
----------------------------------------------
WEEK        | 7      | 100  | 2   | 200
DAY         | 1      | 25   | 2   | 50
```

I thought about using the [lag](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) window function, but now sure how I'd keep track of the days already applied by the previous period.

Comment: Please explain what is going on in each of your three expected outputs.

Comment: What about 6 nights? Is this 2x HALF_WEEK? Then 2 HALF_WEEKs are not a WEEK.

Comment: @S-Man You're right, the example given is not bullet proof (it's just a small piece of a larger puzzle). There are some other factors I'm calculating as well, but have not included them here because they are not germane to this problem at hand.

Comment: @Shane Stillwell Ok, I gave a solution where youncan configure your tiers easily on the fly in a table. The query is very generic to work with any values. How about it?

Comment: @S-man looks good, let me play around with it today. Don’t worry, I won’t forget to approve and up vote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a CTE RECURSIVE query.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0ac709/1

Tier table (which can be dynamically expanded):

```
id  name       days  rate  
--  ---------  ----  ----  
1   WEEK       7     100   
2   DAYS       1     25    
3   HALF_WEEK  3     50    
4   MONTH      30    200
```

Days data:

```
id  num  
--  ---  
1   10   
2   31   
3   30   
4   19   
5   14   
6   108  
7   3    
8   5    
9   1    
10  2    
11  7
```

Result:

```
num_id  num  days                                             total_price  
------  ---  -----------------------------------------------  -----------  
1       10   {"MONTH: 0","WEEK: 1","HALF_WEEK: 1","DAYS: 0"}  150          
2       31   {"MONTH: 1","WEEK: 0","HALF_WEEK: 0","DAYS: 1"}  225          
3       30   {"MONTH: 1","WEEK: 0","HALF_WEEK: 0","DAYS: 0"}  200          
4       19   {"MONTH: 0","WEEK: 2","HALF_WEEK: 1","DAYS: 2"}  300          
5       14   {"MONTH: 0","WEEK: 2","HALF_WEEK: 0","DAYS: 0"}  200          
6       108  {"MONTH: 3","WEEK: 2","HALF_WEEK: 1","DAYS: 1"}  875          
7       3    {"MONTH: 0","WEEK: 0","HALF_WEEK: 1","DAYS: 0"}  50           
8       5    {"MONTH: 0","WEEK: 0","HALF_WEEK: 1","DAYS: 2"}  100          
9       1    {"MONTH: 0","WEEK: 0","HALF_WEEK: 0","DAYS: 1"}  25           
10      2    {"MONTH: 0","WEEK: 0","HALF_WEEK: 0","DAYS: 2"}  50           
11      7    {"MONTH: 0","WEEK: 1","HALF_WEEK: 0","DAYS: 0"}  100
```

The idea:

First I took this query to calculate your result for one value (19):

```
SELECT 
    days / 7 as WEEKS,
    days % 7 / 3 as HALF_WEEKS,
    days % 7 % 3 / 1 as DAYS 
FROM
    (SELECT 19 as days) s
```

Here you can see the recursive structure for the module operation terminated by an integer division. Because a more generic version should be necessary I thought about a recursive version. With PostgreSQL WITH RECURSIVE clause this is possible

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

So thats the final query

```
WITH RECURSIVE days_per_tier(row_no, name, days, rate, counts, mods, num_id, num) AS (
    SELECT 
        row_no, 
        name, 
        days, 
        rate,
        num.num / days, 
        num.num % days, 
        num.id, 
        num.num
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            *, 
            row_number() over (order by days DESC) as row_no             -- C
        FROM 
            testdata.tiers) tiers,                      -- A
            (SELECT id, num FROM testdata.numbers) num  -- B
    WHERE row_no = 1

    UNION

    SELECT 
        days_per_tier.row_no + 1,
        tiers.name, 
        tiers.days,
        tiers.rate,
        mods / tiers.days,                                      -- D
        mods % tiers.days,                                      -- E
        days_per_tier.num_id,
        days_per_tier.num                               
    FROM 
        days_per_tier,  
        (SELECT 
            *, 
            row_number() over (order by days DESC) as row_no 
            FROM testdata.tiers) tiers 
    WHERE days_per_tier.row_no + 1 = tiers.row_no
 ) 
SELECT
    num_id,
    num,
    array_agg(name || ': ' || counts ORDER BY days DESC) as days, 
    sum(total_rate_per_tier) as total_price                    -- G
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        rate * counts as total_rate_per_tier                   -- F
    FROM days_per_tier) s
GROUP BY num_id, num 
ORDER BY num_Id
```

The WITH RECURSIVE contains the starting point of the recursion UNION the recursion part. The starting point simply gets the tiers (A) and numbers (B). To order the tiers due to their days I add a row count (C; only necessary if the corresponding ids are not in the right order as in my example. This could happen if you add another tier).

The recursion part takes the previous SELECT result (which is stored in `days_per_tier`) and calculates the next remainder and integer division (D, E). All other columns are only for holding the origin values (exception the increasing row counter which is responsible for the recursion itself).

After the recursion the counts and rates are multiplied (F) and then grouped by the origin number id which generated the total sum (G)

Edit:
Added the rate function and the sqlfiddle link.

Comment: Works good, but you may want to fix a few typos in the query. Like `FROM testdata.tiers) tiers` is not valid, nor is `FROM testdata.tiers) tiers`. I made a SQLFiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/212ee/1/0 that has your solution showing it works very well.

Comment: @ShaneStillwell I don't see any problems with the query. If the schema and the table were set up right it works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/87e5b/1

Comment: @ShaneStillwell added the rate functionality. See the sqlfiddle above

Comment: My bad, I totally missed that you were using a schema. Thanks for the great answer. Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 0):

Here what you need to do is first fire an SQL command to retrieve all condition and write down the function for your business logic.

For Example.

1. I will fire below query into the database.

   **Select * from table_name order by nights desc**

In result, I will get the data sorted by night in descending order that means first will be 7 then 3 then 1.

2. I will write a function to write down my business logic for example.

Let's suppose I need to find for 11 days.

I will fetch the first record which will be 7 and check it will 11.

```
if(11 > 7){// execute this if in a loop till it's greater then 7, same for 3 & 1
    days = 11-7;
    price += price_from_db;
    package += package_from_db;
}else{
   // goto fetch next record and check the above condition with next record.
}
```

Note: I write down an algorithm instead of language-specific code.

Comment: I could certainly query for the periods and use the app logic to reduce the amount. I was hoping that this could be done purely in SQL.

Comment: @ShaneStillwell This is the business logic, right? so you should have this in your code instead of the database as business logic get change frequently.

Comment: @ShaneStillwell you can use Functions/Procedures to write the same logic and call them through your application. Implementation will be the same in that as well.